# Expose routes on different domains

Tags: node.js

I am struggling with something that doesn't look that hard : let's say I have 2 urls to access my server :

```
http://localhost:80/
```

and an external url

```
http://domain.com/internal/
```

Is there a way to do add a basepath `internal` if the forwarded host is equal to the external url host?

Something like :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers['x-forwarded-host'] === 'domain.com') {
    app.use('/internal', routes);
  } else {
    next();
  }
})
```

Comment: Well sir at the end of the day your server side code will look the same. Let's say my node.js server is the major feeder to the domain in use. If any server makes call to domain.com/xyz or if internally we make call from let's say the angular page to /xyz in the end the same block of code will handle both of them.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But how can I manage that the client code exposed on the server redirects to the correct url (http://domain.com/internal/page2 and not http://domain.com/page2) after making an ajax request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wont be any direct method as in a shortcut to work your way around for personal use cases.

I suggest this simple method though. Let's take example of app.get`('/xyz')` route.

This can be accessed locally via `http://locahost:80/xyz` or `yourdomain.com/xyz` via any application not hosted locally (Unless you make a call using your domainname in your own application).

Add a header element with every request when the call is internal.

Now, whenever our`/xyz` route is called check for that header element using a `if` condition and if the request is made internally you'll have that header element there and then you can simply use either `res.redirect` or any other method that you find useful (Exporting function in current route or anything else you find easy and needful).